# Integrating Siri intents into React native

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native, react-hooks

I have below the Requirements to integrate iOS Siri into React Native.
Basically, I want to build an application that will take certain parameters from a user over voice process it, and return the result.
Simple ex: Todo App,
The user will invoke SIRI by saying

"Hey SIRI create a todo for me "

1. Siri opens up and asks "What is the todo that I need to add "?
2. User says a sample note "reminder to exercise"
3. Siri passes that information to the app and asks for other information "When does the todo need to be completed'?
4. User says some date.
5. Post that the details are processed todo is stored and a success message is shown to the user via SIRI.

Does anyone how this can be achieved in react native ?? I have already explored **react-native-siri-shortcut** and this does not have the above capability.  Thanks in advance, quick help is appreciated.

Comment: what part of the steps you want to achieve doesn't react-native-siri-shortcut cover?
I need to implement similar functionality and it seems like it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: react-native-siri-shortcut  will allow you to add shortcut which will in turn navigate you to specific page. What I want is a conversation, I ask "Hey siri, book a cab", siri should talk back and ask book cab to which location? this is not achievable using react-native-siri-shortcut . Open to hear your thoughts too !!

Comment: got it, yeah, I'm thinking of actually using AppShortcuts and not even bother with siri shorctus since it looks like those will be removed in the future in favour of App Intents.

Comment: Do you think we can create conversations like I mentioned above using app shortcuts in react native? If so, can you explain any package/library to achieve the same ?

Comment: I used app shortcuts to launch the app and deep link into it, but I didn't dive deeper into this.

If I wanted to create something like what you're describing, I'd need to figure a way to communicate between the react-native state, and the native state. I'd probably start with something hacky like sharing state in `UserDefaults` (which both the native and react-native side can read, but there may be more elegant ways to go about this.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you don't need Siri but speech recognition. For example, you can use this library https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice which utilize IOS speech recognition.

Comment: Kirill it will not function when the app is in background or when app is killed. Siri has a intuitive way of handing it by showing prompts and success message to user. I need that in my application.

Comment: you can start your app with siri and then continue recognition with voice library

Comment: Thanks for the response Krill, but it doesn't work like that. I assume you have seen, how SIRI talk back works in iOS. You don't have to open the application SIRI will process your voice and talk back. Only after reading all the parameters you can perform certain action and revert the results.